# Typescript input onchange event.target.value declared in interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In my react and typescript app, I use

```
interface Props {
 text: String;
 ok?: Boolean;
 i?: number;
fn?: (bob: string) => string;
person: Person;
handleChange?: (e: React.ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>) =>    React.ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>}
```

How do I correctly define the typings for input handle change

```
 return (
<div ref={divRef}>
  <div>{text}</div>
  <br />
  <input
    ref={inputRef}
    onChange={ handleChange}
  />
</div>  );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
interface Props {
  // ...
  handleChange?: (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void
}
```